# How to add additional syntax highlighting in vim without sudo

Tags: vim

When vim is used to write python codes, some keywords **in the comments** are highlighting with different colors. And the keywords can be found in `/usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/python.vim`, where there is a line:

```
syn keyword pythonTodo      FIXME NOTE NOTES TODO XXX contained
```

so the words `FIXME`, `NOTE`, `NOTES`, `TODO`, `XXX` **in the comments** will be highlighted.

Now I want to add more words in it, such as adding `DEBUG`, `WARNING` but I don't have sudo so I can not directly edit this file. Is there anyway to solve it? What if I want to specify the color for different words? For example, red for `DEBUG`, yellow for `WARNING`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax highlighting is a two-steps process where each step is handled by separate scripts.

1. The syntax script is in charge of making sense of the syntax of the language: what constitutes a keyword, what constitutes a constant, etc.
2. The color scheme is in charge of defining how those keywords, constants, etc. look.

Now, Vim uses two "runtime directories":

- the "system" one, at `/usr/share/vim/vimXX/` for you, which you shouldn't touch, `sudo` or not,
- the "user" one, at `$HOME/.vim/` for you, where all your customization is supposed to take place.

Both directories have the same structure so the idea is that you can put your custom stuff there and, as long as it respects the default structure, it will be picked up by Vim automatically.

In this case, your job is to write your own syntax script at `$HOME/.vim/syntax/python.vim`, with the following content:

```
syn keyword pythonTodo DEBUG WARNING contained
```

which would give you something like that in a new Vim session:

[image: keywords]

But then comes your second requirement:

> What if I want to specify the color for different words? For example, red for `DEBUG`, yellow for `WARNING`.

The syntax script doesn't care about colors, only about syntax. It is the color scheme that handles colors but it depends on the hard work of the syntax script. If `DEBUG` and `WARNING` are both `pythonTodo`, then they will both be highlighted the same way.

This is a bit more complex, but not by much. Let's do it step-by-step.

1. Define a different highlight group, say `pythonTodoAlt`, only for `WARNING`:

   ```
   syn keyword pythonTodo DEBUG contained
   syn keyword pythonTodoAlt WARNING contained
   ```

   Do you see that `contained` at the end? It means that the highlight group is to be found in other highlight groups that explicitly "contain" it. In this case, `pythonTodo` is supposed to be "contained" in `pythonComment`, which is defined on the line above in the built-in syntax script:

   ```
   syn match   pythonComment    "#.*$" contains=pythonTodo,@Spell
   ```

   As-is, only `pythonTodo` is listed and simply adding the following to your custom syntax script won't work because it will be overridden by the built-in one:

   ```
   syn match pythonComment "#.*$" contains=pythonTodoAlt,pythonTodo,@Spell
   ```

   [image: nocol]

   Bummer.
2. The solution is to add the `containedin` attribute to `pythonTodoAlt`:

   ```
   syn keyword pythonTodoAlt WARNING containedin=pythonComment contained
   ```

   But you are not done yet, because there is no highlighting defined for `pythonTodoAlt`:

   [image: bare]
3. Syntax scripts tend to define lots and lots of highlight groups but it would be ludicrous to expect every color scheme to handle every highlight group, present and future, *explicitly*. That's why syntax script authors link their fancy groups, like `pythonTodo`, to a small set of "default" groups, like `Todo`. In the built-in syntax script, this is done like so:

   ```
   hi def link pythonTodo           Todo
   ```

   Now, this is the time to decide what to do next.

   One possibility is to link `pythonTodoAlt` to a different default group, which would be the most "correct" move, but which one? Is there a default highlight group other than `Todo` that looks the way you want with the current color scheme? Here is an example where I link `pythonTodoAlt` to `Constant` because that's the first one that came to mind:

   ```
   hi def link pythonTodoAlt Constant
   ```

   [image: constant]

   Meh.

   The other possibility is to directly define the looks of `pythonTodoAlt` at the color scheme level. If you don't want or can't edit your color scheme, this is how you do it (see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/romainl/379904f91fa40533175dfaec4c833f2f)):

   ```
   " in $MYVIMRC, before defining your color scheme
   augroup MyColors
       autocmd!
       autocmd ColorScheme * highlight pythonTodoAlt cterm=reverse ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=204 gui=reverse guibg=NONE guifg=#ff5f87
   augroup END
   ```

   [image: done]

Comment: 1. Redefining `pythonComment` group is a bad suggestion. There is `containedin` attribute that allows "to patch" existing groups easily.

Comment: 2. To assign color to a newly created group one can do `hi def guifg=...` instead of messing with autocmd. `hi def` survives hi-clear just like `hi def link` does.

Comment: @Matt thank you. I amended the answer with regard to #1 but surviving `hi clear` is not the point of the provided autocommand so #2 is irrelevant.

Comment: What's the point then? I used to think that colorschemes (almost) always do hi-clear, and so one has "to refresh" customized groups after that. Of course hi-def would be useless for standard groups, as it has lesser priority anyway, but "private" group won't probably be touched, so it's a good application for hi-def.

Comment: The point is to override a highlight group after it may have been defined, not to prevent it from being reset.

Comment: `pythonTodoAlt` is an arbitrary group name, so I don't see how some random colorscheme could know it and tried to (re-)define such group directly.

Comment: Better safe than sorry. Also `:source $MYVIMRC`.